# i18next Reload Resources Refresh Only One Language Problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, internationalization, i18next

I am trying to update i18next resources without restarting app or re-init the instance. To do that I am using `reloadResources()` method. However when this function is triggered, only one language refreshes, the others dont.

I have 3 languages. `de`, `en`, `tr`. I expected to refresh all of them.

Console output:

```
i18next::backendConnector: loaded namespace translations for language de { 'hello-demo': 'Hallo My Friend10' }
i18next::backendConnector: loaded namespace translations for language tr { 'hello-demo': 'Merhaba3' }
i18next::backendConnector: loaded namespace translations for language en { 'hello-demo': 'Hello1' }
i18next: languageChanged en
i18next: initialized {
  debug: true,
  initImmediate: true,
  ns: [ 'translations' ],
  defaultNS: 'translations',
  fallbackLng: {
    'de-CH': [ 'fr', 'it' ],
    'zh-Hant': [ 'zh-Hans', 'en' ],
    es: [ 'fr', 'en' ],
    tr: [ 'de' ],
    xy: [ 'tr' ],
    default: [ 'en' ]
  },
  fallbackNS: false,
  supportedLngs: false,
  nonExplicitSupportedLngs: false,
  load: 'all',
  preload: [ 'de', 'tr', 'en' ],
.
.
.
i18next::backendConnector: loaded namespace translations for language en { 'hello-demo': 'Hello1' }
```

Folder Structure

```
locales
  |de
     |translations.json
  |en
     |translations.json
  |tr
     |translations.json
```

Can you understand why only `en` is updated

## App.JS

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const httpServer = require('http');
const middleware = require('i18next-http-middleware');

const { i18next } = require('./i18n');
const config = require('./config');
const routes = require('./routes');

setInterval(async () => {
  i18next.reloadResources();
}, 15000)

app.use(middleware.handle(i18next));

app.get("/hello", routes.getTestMessage.hello);

httpServer.createServer(app).listen(config.port);
```

## i18n.js

```
const i18next = require('i18next')
const middleware = require('i18next-http-middleware');
const HttpBackend = require('i18next-http-backend');
const FsBackend = require('i18next-fs-backend');
const ChainedBackend = require("i18next-chained-backend");

const config = require('./config');

i18next
  .use(ChainedBackend)
  .use(middleware.LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    debug: config.translation.debug,
    preload: config.translation.preload,
    fallbackLng: config.translation.fallbackLng,
    ns: config.translation.ns,
    defaultNS: config.translation.defaultNS,
    //detection: config.translation.detection,
    //resources: config.translation.resources,
    backend: {
      backends: [
        FsBackend,   // primary
        HttpBackend  // fallback
      ],
      backendOptions: [
        {
          ...config.translation.fsBackendSettings
        },
        {
          ...config.translation.httpBackendSettings
        }
      ]
    }
  });

module.exports = {
  i18next
};
```

## Config.js

```
const local = 'http://localhost:8081'

/* User Settings - feel free to change */
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

/* I18N */
const DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'en';
const OTHER_LANGUAGES = ['de', 'tr'];
const DEFAULT_NAMESPACE = 'translations';
const LOCALE_PATH = 'locales';
const LOCALE_STRUCTURE = '{{lng}}/{{ns}}';
const LOCALE_EXTENSION = 'json'

const config = {
  s3: S3_URL,
  port: PORT,
  translation: {
    debug: true,
    preload: OTHER_LANGUAGES.concat([DEFAULT_LANGUAGE]),
    allLanguages: OTHER_LANGUAGES.concat([DEFAULT_LANGUAGE]),
    fallbackLng: {
      'de-CH': ['fr', 'it'], //French and Italian are also spoken in Switzerland
      'zh-Hant': ['zh-Hans', 'en'],
      'es': ['fr', DEFAULT_LANGUAGE],
      'tr': ['de'],
      'xy': ['tr'],
      'default': [DEFAULT_LANGUAGE]
    },
    ns: [DEFAULT_NAMESPACE],
    defaultNS: DEFAULT_NAMESPACE,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
      formatSeparator: ',',
      format: (value, format) =>
        format === 'uppercase' ? value.toUpperCase() : value,
    },
    detection: {
      lookupHeader: 'accept-language',
      order: ['cookie', 'header', 'querystring'],
      caches: false //['cookie'],
    },
    fsBackendSettings: {
      expirationTime: 15*1000,
      // path where resources get loaded from, or a function
      loadPath: `${__dirname}/${LOCALE_PATH}/${LOCALE_STRUCTURE}.${LOCALE_EXTENSION}`,
      // path to post missing resources
      addPath: `${__dirname}/${LOCALE_PATH}/${LOCALE_STRUCTURE}.${LOCALE_EXTENSION}`,
    },
    httpBackendSettings: {
      loadPath: `${local}/${LOCALE_STRUCTURE}.${LOCALE_EXTENSION}`,
    }
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved immediately

In **Config.JS** When I set

```
fallbackLng: {
'default': OTHER_LANGUAGES.concat([DEFAULT_LANGUAGE])
}
```

Problem solved.